# How to use Python for multinomial maximum likelihood estimation of data?

Tags: python, math, scipy, statistics, multinomial

Data like this:

```
category number
100 1658
101 1801
102 1856
103 1804
104 1779
105 1765
106 1912
107 1976
108 2233
109 2512
110 3133
```

Multinomial maximum likelihood Estimation is used when you know the type of sample and the number of samples of each type.
How to use Python for multinomial maximum likelihood estimation of data?

Comment: Please more or less swap title and prose in body. Write more in the body. Please read [ask] on how else to improve your post.

Comment: I think you might want to use poisson distribution instead. Your dataset looks like it has only univariate values (`number`) and they are large so poisson distribution should be a good approximation of binomial distribution. You can use the [`scipy.stats.fit`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fit.html#scipy.stats.fit) function to be introduced in SciPy 1.9.0 to fit univariate distribution to a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interpreting the data as a sample from a multinomial distribution with k = 10 and n = 22429 (where n and k following the convention used in the Wikipeda article [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)), and you want the maximum likelihood estimate of the event probabilities, you can simply divide the counts for each category by n.  (See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421105/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-parameters-of-multinomial-distribution.)

Here's the simple calculation for your data:

```
In [189]: import numpy as np

In [190]: s = """100 1658
     ...: 101 1801
     ...: 102 1856
     ...: 103 1804
     ...: 104 1779
     ...: 105 1765
     ...: 106 1912
     ...: 107 1976
     ...: 108 2233
     ...: 109 2512
     ...: 110 3133"""

In [191]: category, number = np.loadtxt(s.splitlines(), dtype=int, unpack=True)

In [192]: p = number/number.sum()  # Maximum likelihood estimate

In [193]: p
Out[193]: 
array([0.07392215, 0.08029783, 0.08275001, 0.08043158, 0.07931696,
       0.07869276, 0.08524678, 0.08810023, 0.09955861, 0.11199786,
       0.13968523])
```